# Do I have anything to worry about when switching to a default theme to test for plugin conflictions?

Tags: php, themes, theme-twenty-eleven

WordPress noob here. I want to test a site I'm working on for plugin conflicts. I've heard that switching to a default theme and testing the plugins will do this. My question is, is this going to mess my theme up when I reactivate it? Is it going to be as simple as hitting 'reactivate'?

Comment: No, nothing to worry about. Same as deactivating/reactivating plugin by plugin. Won't lose any plugin related configurations. The only potential loss I can think of is if you save over something, like for example, you go to a page and edit it and then save it, but you've deactivated either a theme or plugin which has removed a content widget and upon save it may not keep the old info you had configured in the widget. It should always be there in the revisions though.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell it is going to affect things, which has configuration specific to the current theme. Out of native functionality that would be most prominently:

- menus (which are assigned to theme locations)
- widgets (which are assigned to sidebars)

This can go further if theme provides sidebars *and* custom widgets for example.

Overall there are rarely *major* issues with switching themes, but there can be plenty of configuration inconvenience, depending on specifics of the site.

Professional developers pretty much exclusively do any development/testing on separate copy of site (usually using local development environment on their computer).

Comment: "Professional developers pretty much exclusively do any development/testing on separate copy of site" +1. Everyone should be doing this